# Scanned wifi results are not showing

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have used the following link [Application to Display All Available WiFi Network and Connect with Specific Network.](http://www.includehelp.com/code-snippets/android-application-to-display-available-wifi-network-and-connect-with-specific-network.aspx) to create application. But it is not showing any results in **android 6.0**  on and showing the scanned wifi networks in  **android 5.0** please help me for this solution. I am not good at network related concepts.

Following is the code for the scanning the wifi list and showing it in activity in list view format

```
public class ScanWifList extends ListActivity {
WifiManager mainWifiObj;
WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
ListView list;
String wifis[];
private int ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
EditText pass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_wifi);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE},
                ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    list=getListView();
    mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    mainWifiObj.startScan();
    // listening to single list item on click
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // selected item
            String ssid = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            connectToWifi(ssid);
            Toast.makeText(ScanWifList.this,"Wifi SSID : "+ssid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}
class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
            wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
        }
        String filtered[] = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (String eachWifi : wifis) {
            String[] temp = eachWifi.split(",");
            filtered[counter] = temp[0].substring(5).trim();//+"\n" + temp[2].substring(12).trim()+"\n" +temp[3].substring(6).trim();//0->SSID, 2->Key Management 3-> Strength
            counter++;
        }
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item,R.id.label, filtered));
    }
}
private void finallyConnect(String networkPass, String networkSSID) {
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);
    // remember id
    int netId = mainWifiObj.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    mainWifiObj.disconnect();
    mainWifiObj.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    mainWifiObj.reconnect();
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
    mainWifiObj.addNetwork(conf);
}
private void connectToWifi(final String wifiSSID) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    dialog.setTitle("Connect to Network");
    TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID1);
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    pass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
    textSSID.setText(wifiSSID);
    // if button is clicked, connect to the network;
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String checkPassword = pass.getText().toString();
            finallyConnect(checkPassword, wifiSSID);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

If possible share anything which will hep me to show scanned wifi networks in **android 6.0 and above**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 6.0 (sdk level 23), the WifiManager's function [getScanResults()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()) requires location permission.

> An app must hold ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to get valid results.

First add into your manifest:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then modify your requestPermissions to add `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: thank you very much . now it is working fine and showing all the wifi networks in my area